# Multiple parllel request not processing in node js in async

Tags: node.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();


module.exports=app;

app.get('/request1', function(req,res){
     request1(function(){
         res.end();
     });

     console.log("req1");
 });

 app.get('/request2',function(req,res){
    console.log("req2");    

    request2(function(){
        res.end();
    });
});

function request1(callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<9999999;i++){
           console.log(i);
        }

        return callback();
     });
 };

 function request2(callback){
     process.nextTick(function(){
         console.log('request2');
         callback();     
     });
 };


app.listen(3000);
```

In this code, I first call /request1 that takes time to process the loop.
But in another tab, I requested /request2 until /request1 is not complete. /request2 is also not executing.

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: It's not possible for two statements of JavaScript to execute at the same time. Asynchronous tasks only run the portion of work that's defined natively (in C, C++, etc.) in parellel. Once the engine begins executing a callback, it's dedicated to it. No other snippet can begin executing. Any other events that occur in native code are simply added to the event loop's queue, waiting for it to finish the current event and eventually pull the next in line.

Comment: Solution is to get rid of the for loop. Why would you even want such a for loop on the server. Node.js is single threaded an only IO operations are asynchrounous (mentioned by others). So you have got to ask your self why you'd have such a for loop.

Comment: thanks for reply,instead of for loop i tried fs.copy(sou,dest,callback) which is i/o operation that takes time huge number of file need to copy so blocking all the request where the problem starts

Comment: so how can i call async app.get() function.

Comment: function request1(callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
      fs.copy(source,dest, function(err){

        return callback();
     });
 };                                                                                                                this also takes time please help me i tried a lot since 1 week how can i get another request while coping another files.

Comment: @user3128578 How is `fs.copy()` defined? That method isn't provided by Node.js itself. And, answers related to it will depend on knowing what it does and how it behaves.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowsk fs-extra module it is present

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is single threaded. It peforms IO and Network Operations in async manner.

Here you are executing for loop which blocks the thread.

So once it will be finished, you will get the request of second request.

Comment: thanks for reply,instead of for loop i tried fs.copy(sou,dest,callback) which is i/o operation that takes time huge number of file need to copy so blocking all the request where the problem starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the concepts of callback , while making request. Its very important to use call back if you are really looking to do process which do some work at same time . How ever it is not possible to do multiple things at same time in node.js. Yet callback gives you a feel of that .